# changes in new branch are being saved to file (and reflected in master branch

Tags: r, git, rstudio

New to git so not sure if I'm phrasing (or searching) things the right way.

I have a git for a few local R packages and I want to create a branch (edit, test) and then merge back to master.

I created a branch through RStudio, however when I edit the function through RStudio (while in the new branch) it's changing the file in the package folder (which is then used by everything in production).

Is there a way to edit and test in a branch in a way that it's not impacting the files that are in production?

Comment: I can't conjure up an exact answer, but maybe you should elaborate on your workflow here.  If you change a file in a certain R package, on _any_ branch, then of course the package will register as having been changed.  The trick here is to make sure that production only uses the version from the master branch, and not from your feature branch.

Comment: I guess the issue could be that the master branch and the feature branch are both sourcing from the same folder/files? So when I save something in a feature branch the file that the master branch is referencing has also been changed... Should the feature branch point to a different folder than the master branch?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a general workflow/guide you may follow.  When generating the R package you actually want to use in production, you should be on the branch which represents the production state.  This might be the `master` branch, or it could be some other branch.  In most programming languages, you would do a build and generate some artifact which can be run.  In the case of R, the package would typically just be a collection of source code.  In this case, you may copy your package to some other location, *outside* of the managed Git folder.  This package is now the reference to be used in production.

Later, if you want to try something new, you may create another branch from `master`.  Note that now as you make changes, it won't affect production, which is using the reference version of the package, in some other location.  When you finish your work, you may merge back to `master`.  You might want to regenerate the production package, if the changes you just made should be reflected.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there anyway to keep the master/production code in place, work on branch in a way that does not affect the production code and then merge to update the master code? Ie how to change the existing framework the least and still be able to test features on an independent branch before merging them.

Comment: Follow what I suggest and it should work.  When you switch branches, _all_ the source code in the Git folder will completely switch to that new branch.  Given that you want a fixed release for each package, then that source code does not really belong in the Git folder.